# setting up netbeans for c

Tags: c, compiler-construction, netbeans

I want to setup a compiler for c in Netbeans. I downloaded and followed the instructions for MiniGW, and now whenever i try to compile a program it says

> Resolve missing native build tools

and the make command and debugger command fields are empty - can anyone help?

If not can someone tell me a good program i can just download to code in c with in windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans is not working with the default make from MinGW.
Here is a link, that might help you resolve your problem:
http://netbeans.org/community/releases/67/cpp-setup-instructions.html

Still if you want a good ide alternative to Netbeans+C (I use this combo under Linux), you can also try [codelite](http://www.codelite.org/). Codelite is a fork for Code::Blocks, currently under development, and has some advanced features that CodeBlocks, for example, is missing.

Eclipse C/C++ is also a good combination.

Comment: Following those instructions doesn't solve the problem. When you compile it still says "Resolve missing native build tools". How do you tell Netbeans where to find these build tools?

Answer (score 1):

From trial and error myself, it seems that if you have followed the [setup and configure instructions](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/67/cpp-setup-instructions.html) correctly, the filepaths should be as follows:

C Compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe

C++ Compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\c++.exe

Make Command: C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe

Answer (score 0):

Good programs that you just download to code C in windows

[Code blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

[Dev C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html)

Comment: DevC++ is NOT  a good tool. It is very buggy and is no longer being developed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed these [setup and configuration instructions](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/cpp-setup-instructions.html)?

Regarding other tools, assuming you want free ones, take your pick [here](http://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/cpp.shtml).
If you're on Windows, I'd recommend [Visual C++ 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I installed the `MSYS` in the root of `C:/` and add the path to path environment in `Windows` also correct it in the `Netbeans`.

1. Download the MSYS from: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/MSYS-1.0.10.exe
2. Install it in `C:/`, and add the address in the o path: `C:\msys\1.0\bin`
3. Edit make.exe address in NetBeans: `Tools > Options >